# Display a customized dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have problem to display names of different category as a dropdownlist + display a general name that is a selection of every category. I need this in order to create a search function.

The orginal categori List is:

- Datorer & IT
- Filosofi & Religion
- Sport & Fritid
- Djur & Natur
- Konst & Musik
- Psykologi & Pedagogik

The request to display as dropdownlist:

- All Category
- Datorer & IT
- Filosofi & Religion
- Sport & Fritid
- Djur & Natur
- Konst & Musik
- Psykologi & Pedagogik

<%@ Import Namespace="BokButik1"%>

<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%> 

<fieldset> 
    <legend>Edit Album</legend> 

        <%: Html.DropDownList("KategoriID", new SelectList(ViewData["Kategoris"] as IEnumerable, "KategoriID", "KategoriNamn", Model.Kategoris))%> 



    <p> 
        <input type="submit" value="Save" /> 
    </p> 
</fieldset> 

<% } %>



namespace BokButik1.ViewModels
{
    public class SokningIndexViewModel
    {
        public List<Kategori> Kategoris { get; set; }
    }
}


namespace BokButik1.Controllers
{
    public class SokningController : Controller
    {


        private IKategoriRepository myIKategoriRepository = new KategoriRepository();

        //
        // GET: /Sokning/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var SokningIndexViewModel = new SokningIndexViewModel 
            {
                Kategoris = myIKategoriRepository.HamtaAllaKategoriNamn()       
            };

            return View(SokningIndexViewModel);
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a new `Kategori` item to the beginning of your list, however it appears you may also be mixing your Model and ViewData up

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

  var SokningIndexViewModel = new SokningIndexViewModel() 
  {
    Kategoris = myIKategoriRepository.HamtaAllaKategoriNamn();       
  };
  //add the 'all catagory' item
  SokningIndexViewModel.Kategoris.Insert(0, new Kategori() {
    KategoriID = 0,
    KategoriNamn = "All Category"
  });
  return View(SokningIndexViewModel);

}
```

In your view

```
<%: Html.DropDownList("KategoriID", new SelectList(Model.Kategoris as IEnumerable, "KategoriID", "KategoriNamn"))%>
```